# member access for class

Tags: c++, class

A class is defined as follows:

```
class Widget {
  double wgt;
public:
  Widget(double w) : wgt(w) {assert(w>=0);}
  double weight() const { return wgt;}
  double & weight() { return wgt;}

};
```

Why it has to include two implementations for method

> weight

For the first one, what's the effect of put const there? And for the second one, what's the effect of putting & there?

The code of `Widget(double w) : wgt(w) {assert(w>=0);}`  should work as the constructor, but how to understand wgt(w) here?

We can use this class as

```
Widget w(35);
cout <<w.weight()<<endl;
```

But I cannot see how the w(35) is used to create an object through the defined constructor?

Moreover, which implement of function weight is used for this w.weight?

Comment: Is this homework? It sure looks like these are homework questions.

Answer (score 1):

const is a contract between you and the compiler saying that you won't mutate the object (in this case the compiler will error when you try to modify the value returned by that getting. When using the & getting you will get a reference for that object.

Const -> Non-mutable value

& (Reference) -> 'Address of' reference to mutable value.

Answer (score 1):

> The code of Widget(double w) : wgt(w) {assert(w>=0);} should work as the constructor, but how to understand wgt(w) here?

The `: wgt(w)` is the initialization list for this constructor. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6, for example. So `Widget w(35);` creates and constructs a variable `w` of type `Widget` whose `wgt` data member has an initial value of 35.

> Why it has to include two implementations for method `weight`?

It doesn't "have" to, and a lot of people would say this is bad form. There is no difference between supplying these two public functions and making the data member `wgt` public. As far as why two goes: One of the functions, the `const` qualified version, can only be used as an rvalue, a value on the right hand side of an equal sign. The non-const version can be used as an lvalue (on the left hand side of an equal sign) or as an rvalue. For example,

```
w.weight() = 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, const guarantees that calling the method won't change any of the widget object's members.

For the second one, & means that a reference instead of a copy of the wgt member will be returned. Because it is a reference, you can change the value of wgt by doing

```
Widget w(3.3);
w.weight() = 45.3;
```

If & were not present, you could still write the code as in my example, but w.wgt would still have it's original value of 3.3 even after the line that seems to assign 45.3 to it.

wgt(w) in the constructor means that when the object is constructed, the initial value given to the wgt member of the class will be the value that is passed as an argument to the constructor.

You can find out yourself which function is called when doing w.weight() by adding your own cout prints to the two methods that print out different things and see which one gets printed out.